# customize FaultException error

Tags: wcf, faultexception

I created a wcf service and I'm using FaultException to throw errors to the client, however in client when I call the operation and there is an error in the server I get this kind of error message:
[Error message snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYfym.jpg)

I only want the highlighted error message not this html page! I have to find the error by javascript and it's not like a best practice, I want to return only error to client.
thanks for your help